# Is this valid jquery code?

Tags: jquery, css, width

My intention is to increase the width of an element by 10px on mouseover and decrease it back 10px on mouseover, which is the default width in the css.

Based on other forum answers I thought I could use:

```
 $("#theelement").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({"width": $(this.width()+10}) 
  }
 $("#theelement").mousleave(function() {
    $(this).css({"width": $(this.width()-10}) 
  }
```

Things aren't working right now, and am not sure if this is the culprit or not. In plain javascript we add "px" I know, but not sure about this. In any case I'd like to change the element's width on the fly without knowing its static width.

Comment: have you check the console before ask? I thought there should be a clear explaination on what's the error of your code

Comment: @user3274901, check out my code

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code: Simple and short!!



$(function(){
    $("#theelement").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css({"width": $(this).width()+10}); 
        },
        function(){
            $(this).css({"width": $(this).width()-10});
        }
    );                             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, you are missing  `);` at couple and `$(this.width()` needs to be `$(this).width()`

```
 $("#theelement").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "width": $(this).width() + 10
    });
 }); //Here
 $("#theelement").mousleave(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "width": $(this).width() - 10
    })
 }); //And Here
```

*As a side note:*

You can simply use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
 $("#theelement").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        "width": $(this).width() + 10
    });
 }, function () {
    $(this).css({
        "width": $(this).width() - 10
    });
 });
```

Comment: Is `this.width()` a valid one.? And he did not close the bracket `$(`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, I did noticed that

Comment: But before the recent updates you did not notice that, That's why I just pointed that to you. :)

Comment: Ah stupid me, a parenthesis. So using hover is the way it seem, is it better supported than mouseenter, or something?

Comment: @user3274901, Its just a short-hand nothing more than that

Comment: @user3274901, As you are new to SO consider accepting the best answer which helped you most __(not necessarily mine)__. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

No, `$(this.width()` should be like this `$(this).width();` and as the previous answerer said you are having a syntax error in missing `);`

```
$("#theelement").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({"width": $(this).width()+10}) 
  });

 $("#theelement").mousleave(function() {
    $(this).css({"width": $(this).width()-10}) 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#theelement').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).width(function (index, value) {
        return value + 10;
    });
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).width(function (index, value) {
        return value - 10;
    });
});
```

This will definitely work. Check it out !